# Best way to change presentation based on class variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a class that could be two different logical types depending on the value of a variable. Just as an example, consider the case of a `Human` class that could be male or female. In my presentation I would like to be able to distinguish between males and females and display differently accordingly, but am not sure what is the canonical way to do so.

My current approach is to use a getter function:

```
var human = new Human('male');
if (human.getGender() === 'male') {
    //display male ...
} else {
    //display female...
}
```

However I could also use a static function defined on the class or in a utility class:

```
var instance = new Human('male');
if (Human.isMale(instance)) { ... }
else { ... }
```

And I could also make use of inheritance with `instanceof`:

```
if (human instanceof Male) { ... }
```

I had decided not to use separate `Male` and `Female` classes because both would have the exact same variables and functions in my application. Since there is no different behavior between the two except in presentation it seems redundant to define an extra class. Is my reasoning here correct? And out of these options, and any others I might have missed, what are the benefits to using each method?

Comment: it depends on personal preference and how you're going to use them. `isMale` and `isFemale` are probably what i'd go with, but i'd set them as properties in the constructor rather than functions.

Comment: @sgroves why implement the two? is someone is not male, then she is female? :P

Comment: why not? they're just properties. makes them easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest assigning them as properties in your `Human` constructor:

```
function Human(gender) {
    this.isMale = (gender == 'male');
    this.isFemale = (gender == 'female'); // !this.isMale works too

    // ...
}
```

Then on any `Human` object, you can check them without calling a function:

```
var instance = new Human('male');
if (instance.isMale) {
    // do something for a male
}
if (instance.isFemale) {
    // do something for a female
}
```

You may not need to assign both `isMale` and `isFemale`, but I think it will make your code easier to read and use. Besides, gender is not binary, and this leaves room for adding other gender choices.

Comment: Thanks, this is much cleaner than any of the choices I was considering. Good point about gender not being binary.